# API Access denied and 403 error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, api, rest-api

`api/rest/customers` is not working. I am `Error 403 access denied` though its working for products but not for orders.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your hosting service provider, you may be triggering a false-positive on `modsecurity` that they'll need to whitelist.

Comment: For localhost what i need to do? @Moose

Comment: Ensure that your `user → role` has permission for the API call & that `system → permission → role` is configured correctly.

Comment: can i get help regard How to convert SOAP Magento Objects to XML Values? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/250148/57334  @Moose